# Export ONLY face normals of a mesh

Tags: mesh, normals, file-format, collision

I'm very new to Blender and just trying to accomplish some simple meshes for my game project. In the process of developing some collision meshes I'm looking to create some meshes that ONLY export the face normals, no vertex normals or anything.

This seems to work on simple cubes (resulting in 6 face normals) but when trying to create slightly more complex objects (like a hexagon tile with angled sides) I get far more normals than there are faces.

There doesn't seem to be an option in Blender to just export the face normals. I'm trying to output as little normals into the object files as possible since my collision detection is going to be looping through each normal in an SAT check and the more defunct normals I have to deal with the more bloat the collision detection is going to have.

Anything I might be missing in Blender that would allow me to accomplish this?

Thanks.